# On ACM varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A smooth projective variety $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ is called Arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay if it's homogeneous coordinate ring $S_X$ is Cohen-Macaulay or equivalently if $\text{dim}(S_X) =\text{depth}(S_X)$.

So this means in particular that every smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3$ is Arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Any hypersurface (or more generally, complete intersections) in a projective space is ACM, smooth or not.

Comment: Thanks@Mohan for the comment.